# Javascript- How to save onClick function results into two different variable?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am a learner of JavaScript. I have two sets of drop-down options and want to save the changes in the drop-down selection as two different variables upon clicking one button (update).

Here is my function to get the variables:

```
function jsDropDown() {
        //Get the start date upon changing the button
        var start_date = document.getElementById("days1").value + "-" + 
            document.getElementById("months1").value + "-" +
            document.getElementById("years1").value;
        var end_date = document.getElementById("days2").value + "-" + document.getElementById("months2").value + "-" +
            document.getElementById("years2").value;
    }
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomaSaha/eh1w7k6a/

The idea is when the user selects 01-February-2019, this is saved as start_date and 
            when the user selects 31-December-2019, this is saved as end_date.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Is something not working?  What's your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few points:

1) Your year dropdown texts are different than the values, 1982 is mapped with 1995 and so on.

2) Your function is correct but cannot be called because fiddle has some different setup and in result it throws `referenceError` (function undefined)

So you have two choices:

(a) move your function in script tag

OR

(b) use `document.ready` function from jquery

see demo with 2(a) https://jsfiddle.net/fgrt1qvh/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Bilal Siddiqui. The dropdown texts were wrong.  Now it's working.

Comment: @ mohit dutt, the problem was the new variables were not generating the values in closole.log. Now it's working. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @TomaSaha: If the only "problem" was that you had a typo in your values then it's likely best to just delete this whole question.  It serves little value and has attracted only negative attention as a result.

Comment: @David he cant delete, question with answers will not allow to delete. Instead he have only choice to accept an answer :)

Comment: @David the problem was not only the typo, the positioning of the script tag as well. The solution was helpful!

Comment: @TomaSaha this is emberrasing with fiddle. js functions aren't directly available to html. it only works with jqery perfectly. if you use stackoverflow's inbuilt `<>` editor then that will work as per expectation.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

hey please go through the above snap , see in console is it working perfectly as the way you want .
and find the below code attached

```
<Div class="dropDown1">

  Day: <select name="days" id="days1">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>

  </select>
  Month: <select name="months" id="months1">
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>

  </select>

  Year: <select name="years" id="years1">
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>

  </select>
</Div>
End Date <Div class="dropDown2">

  Day: <select name="days" id="days2">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>

  </select>
  Month: <select name="months" id="months2">
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>

  </select>

  Year: <select name="years" id="years2">
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>

  </select>
</Div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Update</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {debugger
  //Get the start date upon changing the button
  var start_date = document.getElementById("days1").value + "-" + document.getElementById("months1").value + "-" +
    document.getElementById("years1").value;
  var end_date = document.getElementById("days2").value + "-" + document.getElementById("months2").value + "-" +
    document.getElementById("years2").value;
console.log('start_date', start_date);
console.log('end_date', end_date)
}

</script>
```